# Club set in a finite support iteratiot of c.c.c forcing notions.

Tags: set-theory, forcing, infinitary-combinatorics

I'm reading the Baumgartner and Dordal paper "Adjoining dominating functions" and I have a problem with the Theorem  4.1 proof.

My problem is the following: Suppose that $P$ is a c.c.c-forcing notion and $P_\lambda$ is the forcing resulting of iterate, with finite support, the forcing $P$ $\lambda$-times (here $\lambda$ is a regular cardinal bigger than $\omega_1$). Let $\{a_\alpha:\alpha<\lambda\}$ be a descending tower in $V^{P_\lambda}$. Consider the set $C:=\{\gamma<\lambda:\{a_\alpha:\alpha<\gamma\}\in V^{P_\gamma}\}$. The  authors says that with a standar argument we can find a club set inside of $C$.  My question is, which is such "standar argument"? Can someone tell me the way to find such club set?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, I'm sure.  But I don't see as this set can be $\lambda$. Can you explain me your intuition?

Comment: Sorry, misread a $\gamma$ as a $\lambda$, my mistake.

Comment: Do you know that every real $a_\alpha$ appears at some step $\gamma < \lambda$? (through nice names)